# How to stack django model saving calls in case an error occurs?

Tags: django, orm

My web app needs massive load from csv files. Files may have reference errors. How can I save "softly" each row and rollback all saved records if an error occurs?

I'm using django command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should want to use [Transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#module-django.db.transaction) to guarantee atomicity on database.

This way you can set your block of code to persist on database only if all block is successfully completed. If any Exception occur, the transaction will be rolled back.

See this example code:

```py
from django.db import transaction

def your_command_func():
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This block of code executes inside a transaction.
        line = read_from_csv()
        has_error = validate_line(line)

        if has_error:
            raise YourException("something went wrong.")
```

Comment: Perfect answer bro. Thank you.